# C# navigate through forms

Tags: c#, forms, hide, show

Is it possible to change page in c# visual studio windows forms without the user noticing the page change ?

I tried changing forms through a menustrip with this code:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.Show();
            this.Hide();
```

But the screen blinks !

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Start your application with Form2. No need to change it.

Comment: You mean, the blinking occurs once but you even do not want this one blink?

Comment: you can use `panels`, hide and show them to act like forms

Comment: cant you use a TabControl?

Comment: Can I create TabControl like pages but without the "tab" ?

Answer (score 2):

Forms are not pages. If you want to display different contents as pages, then you'd probably be better off creating your "pages" as `UserControls`. You create them much like `Forms`. Then place one of them on a form with the `Dock` property set to `Fill`. When you want to display another page, replace the user control by another one.

Changing the page:

```
Control page = null;
switch (pageNumber) {
    case 1:
        page = new UserControl1();
        break;
    case 2:
        page = new UserControl2();
        break;
}
page.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
if (previousPage != null) {
    frm.Controls.Remove(previousPage);
}
frm.Controls.Add(page);
previousPage = page;
```

You will have to define this in the form:

```
private Control previousPage;
private int pageNumber = 1;
```

Also somewhere you will have to determine the next page number.